# Estrutura de classe para

Tags: c#, xml, serialização

Tenho o seguinte XML retornado por um serviço:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<mensagem tipo="0000" version="1.0">
  <registro tipo="0000" version="1.0">
    <header>
      <campos que não posso disponibilizar/>
    </header>
    <erros>
      <qtdMensagem>3</qtdMensagem>
      <erro>
        <codigo>B0000</codigo>
        <descricao>corrigir campo x</descricao>
        <codigo>B0000</codigo>
        <descricao>corrigir campo y</descricao>
        <codigo>B0000</codigo>
        <descricao>campo z invalido</descricao>
      </erro>
    </erros>
  </registro>
</mensagem>
```

Estou tendo problemas ao deserializar

```
    public void ReadXML<T>(ref T AObject, string AXml)
    {
        Errors.Clear();

        try
        {
            byte[] encodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AXml);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encodedString);
            ms.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            ser.UnknownAttribute += new XmlAttributeEventHandler(Serializer_UnknownAttribute);
            ser.UnknownElement += new XmlElementEventHandler(Serializer_UnknownElement);
            ser.UnknownNode += new XmlNodeEventHandler(serializer_UnknownNode);
            ser.UnreferencedObject += new UnreferencedObjectEventHandler(Serializer_UnreferencedObject);

            AObject = (T)ser.Deserialize(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new UException(1, ex, "Erro ao serializar.");
        }
    }
```

chamando:

```
Msg RetMsg = new Msg();
ReadXML<Msg>(ref RetMsg, XML);
```

apenas carrega o primeiro erro/descricao, e para os demais tenho erros de column unknow codigo/descricao

vejam como está a classe:
(sem a parte do header que por questões contratuais não posso expor)

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "erros")]
public class ErrosClas
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "qtdMensagem")]
    public string QtdMensagem { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "erro")]
    public List<Erro> AErro { get; set; }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "erro")]
    public class Erro
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "codigo")]
        public string Codigo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "descricao")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Já testei alterando (XmlElement, XmlArray, XmlArrayItem), procurei mais de 2 horas na internet sem sucesso, devo estar usando as tags erradas na busca.

Comment: pois é a formatação de <erro> tá um tanto estranha, representaria um array de código e outro de descricao

Comment: Ta errado a formatação desse XML! é o primeiro problema! erro. verifique isso.

Comment: só para teste, tenta 
`public List<string> Codigo { get; set; }`
`public List<string> Descricao { get; set; }`

Comment: o XML é de uma financeira (banco) não tem como mudar, eles insistem em coisas como tag vazia obrigatoriamente ser <tag></tag>. Testei com a sugestão do Leandro Angelo (List<string> Codigo/Descricao e funcionou. Envie como resposta para marcar como correta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma vez que o elemento `<erro>` é composto por diversos `<codigo>` e `<descricao>`
Seu mapeamento deve contemplar listas ou arrays para os mesmos:

```
  <erro>
    <codigo>B0000</codigo>
    <descricao>corrigir campo x</descricao>
    <codigo>B0000</codigo>
    <descricao>corrigir campo y</descricao>
    <codigo>B0000</codigo>
    <descricao>campo z invalido</descricao>
  </erro>
```

Logo seu mapeamento pode refletir da seguinte forma

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "erros")]
public class ErrosClas
{
    //...

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "erro")]
    public class Erro
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "codigo")]
        public List<string> Codigo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "descricao")]
        public List<string> Descricao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Porém ao processar o resultado no seu sistema você vai precisar realizar o pareamento desses valores (Codigo/Descricao) através de seus índices, porque nesse caso você vai receber duas listas distintas que devem estar pareadas, mas não existe uma regra explícita que garanta isso.